# Is str(Bool) locale dependent

Tags: python, locale

When in a python script I write

```sh
>>> v = True
>>> str(v).upper()
'TRUE'
```

can I assume that `'TRUE'` will always be the result, or can I have a translation of True in user terminal language (e.g `'WAHR'` if user terminal is in German)?

Comment: Yes, it will always give the same result

Comment: Just to preempt what might be a horrid use case, if you're going to write `if str(v).upper() == 'TRUE':` , Please don't. you can directly check the truthiness of the boolean. (`if v:`)

Comment: @Paritosh Singh don't worry, I want to generate a file and be sure that the file only contains "TRUE" or "FALSE" for booleans value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always be `TRUE`, but if you want to hardcode it yourself:

```
print( 'TRUE' if v else 'FALSE' )
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` will give the same result for a boolean regardless of the user terminal language